# CSS3 Pie border disappeared

Tags: css, css3pie

I am trying to use CSS3Pie in my asp.net mvc 3.0 application
But in IE versions lover than 9 the border just disappeared completely.
here is my css

```
.box
{
    margin:auto;
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #86b0ca;
    margin:10px 0 10px 0;
    behavior: url("/Scripts/htc/PIE.htc"); /*if i remove that the border not disappeared but square in old IE versions*/
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to this box, then go and read the documentation!

http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/ has a section explaining why you need to do this, I'm not sure why it's not in the getting started guide.

Comment: i've read that http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/ but probably they saying about `position:relative` somewhere else